# Tensorflow One-Hot

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow (And neural networks) and i am working on a simple classification problem. Would like to ask 2 questions.

Say i have 120 labels of a permutation of [1,2,3,4,5]. Is it really necessary for me to One-Hot encode before feeding it into my graph? If yes, should i encode before feeding into tensorflow?

And if i do One-Hot encode, the softmax prediction will give [0.001 0.202 0.321……0.002 0.0003 0.0004]. Running arg_max will produce the right index. How would i get tensorflow to return me the correct label instead of a one-hot result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So your input are 120 labels in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} (each of which can be either digit from 1 to 5)?

```
# Your input, a 1D tensor of 120 elements from 1-5.
# Better shift your label space to 0-4 instead.
labels = labels - 1

# Now convert to a 2D tensor of 120 x 5 onehot labels.
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 5)

# Now some computations.
....

# You end up with some onehot_output
# of the same shape as your labels (120x5).
# As you said, arg_max will give you the index of the result,
# which is a 1D index label of 120 elements.
output = tf.argmax(onehot_output, axis=1).

# You might want to shift back to {1,2,3,4,5}.
output = output + 1
```

Comment: Hi Guinny, thanks for your answer. I was trying out your answer but it wouldn't work with a tf.float32 type as input. I had to keep this type as there are operations which needed it to be tf.float32 down the stream. I tried tf.cast(labels, tf.float32) before the downstream computation but that didn't help.